# Getting an error at NGWerDriver ExecuteAsyncScript() as 'script timeout: result was not received in 10 seconds" after navigating new page

Tags: c#, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, page-object-gem

SuccesfulLogin() is main test case from execution getting started. I am using NGWerDriver with C# language.

Login Page code working fine but getting error while performing action on next page homologo element.

```
public void SuccesfulLogin()
{
    LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
    loginPage.ValidLogin(ReadSetting("URL"),ReadSetting("Username"), ReadSetting("Password"), ReadSetting("ConsortiumCode"));
    HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver);
    homePage.HomePageDisplay();
    //Assert.AreEqual(true, value);
}

public HomePage HomePageDisplay()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Inside Home Page");
    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    Homelogo.Click();
    ngDriver.WaitForAngular();
    return this;
}
```

[Error Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSAX7.png)

Comment: What is the text of the error you are getting?

Comment: Added error snapshot "OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: 'script timeout: result was not received in 10 seconds
  (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.121)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)'"

Comment: On the line where you indicate the error occurs, 

`return jsExecutor.ExecuteAsycScript(script, args);`

Can you show me the code or let me know what `script` and `args` you are passing in to this function